REGEXP_REPLACEでグループ化した文字列にファンクションを適用したい
Oracle 19cでレコードから不定個のハイフンで区切られた文字列(例えばHOGE-FUGAやA-B-C、-D-E--など)を取得し、ハイフンで分割したそれぞれの文字列をストアドファンクションで加工し、再度結合しようとしています。
REGEXP_REPLACEの正規表現グループを使用することで、文字列の分割を試みました。
しかし想定通りに動作しません。
-- 確認用SQL
select REGEXP_REPLACE('A-BC', '([^-]+)', lower('X\1')) from dual -- xA-xBC
 
-- やりたいSQL
-- select REGEXP_REPLACE('A-BC', '([^-]+)', my_func('\1')) from dual

上記のSQLを実行すると、確認用SQLがxa-xbcとならずxA-xBCになってしまいます。
やりたいSQLをデバッグすると、my_funcに\1が渡され、ファンクション実行後に\1がグループ文字列に置換されるようです。
グループ文字列をファンクションに直接渡す引数やオプションはあるのでしょうか。
(もしOracleのバージョンが上がると解決する場合もご教示ください)
下記のようなコードの他、素直にINSTRとSUBSTRを使う方法や階層問合わせなどで対応自体は可能なのですが、とREGEXP_REPLACEで解決出来たら便利なので質問させていただきます。
declare
  s constant varchar2(50) := 'A-BC-DEF';
  sub varchar2(50);
  cnt number;
begin
  cnt := length(s) - length(replace(s, '-')) + 1; -- ハイフンの個数を取得し、その回数分ループ
  for i in 1..cnt loop
    sub := regexp_substr(s, '(.*?)(-|$)', 1, i, NULL, 1); -- i の値でヒットした位置のインデックスを変化させる
    dbms_output.put_line(lower(sub)); -- 任意のファンクションで加工
  end loop;
end;

